# Does IIED (emotional distress) apply to infidelity and if no, why not?

Tags: family-law, emotional-distress

I found this interesting corner of law called IIED (Intentional Infliction of Emotional Distress).

https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/intentional_infliction_of_emotional_distress

To a layman's eye, infidelity seems to fit neatly into 4 bullet points of stated definition at this link, if intent can be shown:

- It's an act
- It is generally considered outrageous
- It's well known that infidelity victims are likely to suffer mental health effects (I even saw mentions it's equivalent to PTSD)
- Conduct clearly causes the distress.

If this is the case, can IIED get applied to a spousal infidelity, and if not, why wouldn't it? I'm looking ideally for a case where it was requested by the accuser, and the court either allowed it thus setting a precedent, or gave an explanation for rejecting it.

Since "well in this case, I don't see enough evidence that causing emotional distress was a *purpose* of defendant, merely an unfortunate consequence" is an obvious rebuttal, I'm hopefully looking for a more interesting case, such as where there is evidence proving that accused had anticipated emotional distress and it was a desired goal.

Jurisdiction is USA. And just to clarify, this is specifically regarding "*intentional*", not "negligent" ED.

Comment: I found this which may be relevant but can't quite figure out what it all means: https://digitalcommons.law.umaryland.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3001&context=mlr&httpsredir=1&referer=

Comment: I think the larger problem you're going to run into is that infidelity typically happens surreptitiously. If Spouse A is trying to conceal the act, it's going to be hard to establish that his intent was to hurt Spouse B. I think negligent infliction of emotional distress is going to be the more viable claim in most cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does IIED (emotional distress) apply to infidelity and if no, why not?

Generally speaking, infidelity falls short of liability for IIED.

[*Clark v. Clark*, 867 S.E.2d 704 (2021)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/inncco20211207353) appears to be one recent exception, but that is because there the defendants' conduct allegedly entailed more than mere infidelity, such as "*sen[ding] at least one email to Plaintiff in which Defendant Barrett told Plaintiff she "was a bad mother, that [she was] uneducated... [she] was a bad wife," and that Plaintiff came "from an unsuccessful family"*" (quotation marks in original), conduct that the court seemed to associate with elements of *Watson v. Dixon* (i.e., frightening the plaintiff, humiliation, etc.), cited in the preceding paragraph of the *Clark* decision.

The difficulty for prevailing on a claim of IIED generally lies in proving that "*the defendant's conduct was [...] so outrageous that it is not tolerated by civilized society*", [*Rogers v. Louisville Land Co.*, 367 S.W.3d 196, 207 (2012)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/intnco20120419647). The notion that infidelity "*is not tolerated by civilized society*" is hard to establish. For instance, many people do not very often distance themselves from a co-worker, friend, or acquaintance merely on grounds of that person being known to cheat on that person's spouse or partner. Also the fact that adultery is hardly ever prosecuted despite being prohibited in a jurisdiction's penal code reflects the extent of societal and governmental tolerance to infidelity.